# how to call a non-AJAX function from within an AJAX function

Tags: functions, ajax

I have added an AJAX function to my installation and confirmed that it works successfully.

I have an AJAX function `local_commit_button`, and from inside that function I am trying to call a regular php function called `emit()` but everytime I try to call emit I get a 500 with almost no explanation.

I cannot find instructions on how to do this, does anyone know how this can be done?

```
public function local_commit_button( $args ) {
     emit( $args );
}
```

I tried registering the emit function with ajax but that did not do it.

script.js:

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.akc-dev-btn').on('click', function () {
            console.log('pitter');

            var data = [];

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',   // Adding Post method
                url: local_script.ajaxurl, // Including ajax file
                data: {
                    "action": "local_commit_button",
                    "data": data,
                    "nonce": local_script.nonce
                },
                success: function (response) { // Show returned data using the function.
                    console.log('patter');
                }

            });


        });


    });

})(jQuery);
```

added to the class constructor:

```
add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'local_commit_button' ] );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_local_commit_button', [ $this, 'local_commit_button' ] );
```

actual function:

```
 /**
     * AJAX function.  Runs PHP on button click
     *
     * @since 0.1
     */
    public function local_commit_button($args = 'new' ) {
        check_ajax_referer( 'local_script', 'nonce' );

       emit( $args );

        wp_send_json_success( [
            'message' => 'secure success',
        ] );

    }
 public function emit( $args ) {
   // no code yet
}
```

the error is resolved, explanation below

Comment: There’s no reason you can’t do this. There no such thing as AJAX and non-AJAX functions. It’s just PHP. You are getting an error because there’s something wrong with the code. What do your error logs say? I can see that local_commit_button accepts an $args argument, but an admin-ajax.pho request will not pass any arguments to fallback functions, which will cause an error.

Comment: how did you implement your AJAX? Are you trying to make AJAX calls to a PHP file in your plugin/theme? Are you sure this is a WordPress problem and not a generic PHP problem? When you call `emit()` what are you trying to do? Have you checked your PHP error log to find out what the error message is?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Oh that makes sense.  Is there a way to send `emit()` with an argument?

Comment: @TomJNowell the question is updated with the code

Comment: @steve8094 you mentioned the error is resolved in your edit but you did not post an answer/solution below, have you answered the question? Or have I misunderstood? Do you still need help? If you've found the solution to your problem you should write an answer below so people can upvote it and so the site doesn't keep trying to find you an answer

Comment: @TomJNowell I am blocked from posting an answer to this question, an answer I gave was downvoted.  I'm not sure how to restore my answering-capabilities but this question is resolved so thank you.